# How to upload unity web-player game to Google drive?

Tags: web, unity-game-engine, google-drive-api, dropbox

I want to know how can i upload my webplayer game to Google drive. I see several game are working on Google drive my games are uploaded to dropbox but i also want to upload on google drive

Comment: Copying the html and unity3d files must work then you must use public address of the html file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow this tutorial for hosting a webpage on google drive:

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

Complete steps:

1. Upload a folder with your build (.html and .unity3d file) on google drive
2. Share this folder with "anyone on the internet". Right click -> Share -> Advanced -> Public on the web -> Done
3. Get shareable link of your html file (inside shared folder). Right click -> Share -> Get shareable link
4. Copy the ID from this link (which looks like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/[here_goes_your_id]/view?usp=sharing) to this template: https://googledrive.com/host/[here_goes_your_id] which will be the link to your game.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can't.

> Beginning August 31, 2015, web hosting in Google Drive for users and developers will be deprecated. Google Apps customers can continue to use this feature for a period of one year until August 31, 2016, when serving content via googledrive.com/host/doc id will be discontinued.

[Source](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html?visit_id=1-636155954046183033-808926831&hl=en&rd=1)